# Blazor Virtualize won't load more items

Tags: scroll, blazor-webassembly, ui-virtualization

I have a WASM Blazor app with a simple `Virtualize` items that use `ItemsProvider` to get the items:

```
<Virtualize Context="bobina" ItemSize="500" ItemsProvider="@GetCustomersProvider" OverscanCount="0">
```

this is the method:

```
private async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<Bobina>> GetCustomersProvider(ItemsProviderRequest request)
    {
        List<Bobina> lista = await Bobina.GetLista(request.StartIndex, request.Count);
        return new ItemsProviderResult<Bobina>(lista, lista.Count());
    }
```

the `Bobina.GetLista` performs an http call to an harperDB and get some records:

```
$"SELECT * FROM dev.bobine order by nome offset {skip} rows FETCH NEXT {take} ROWS ONLY";
```

For test purpose I have set the `ItemSize` to `500px`, so the method load only few items (inside the db there are only 7 items).

When the first call is done the `Virtualize` component renders some items but when I scroll down the page nothing happens.

It's supposed to call the server again to fetch some others records, but it doesn't do.

I have seen many online sample that do the same things I do and all works fine.
I use the [mudblazor](https://mudblazor.com/) componets, so I thought to comment all these components and render a simple `<table>` tag, but the result is the same.

Where am i wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

[Here](https://github.com/Raystorm7/TestBlazor) the full code sample.

Comment: Hi, I have shared the full code of the application in the link.
Don't like we transfert? I could upload the code to another site, please tell me what is a "trustworthy code sharing site". 
The code is too big (full application) to post here, so I have upload the full source code.

Comment: A minimal repro is what is needed, not your whole application as a download.

Comment: @MisterMagoo I have replaced we transfer link with github repo. This is fine for you? Could you help me to solve the issue, now? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Virtualize' component needs to know the total number of items available to determine when it should fetch additional items as the user scrolls.

I think the second parameter of the `ItemsProviderResult` constructor should be the total number of items available, not the count of items in the current fetched list.

```
private async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<Bobina>> GetCustomersProvider(ItemsProviderRequest request)
{
    List<Bobina> lista = await Bobina.GetLista(request.StartIndex, request.Count);
    int totalItemCount = await Bobina.GetTotalItemCount(); // Add a method to get the total number of items in the database
    return new ItemsProviderResult<Bobina>(lista, totalItemCount);
}
```

And then:

```
public static async Task<int> GetTotalItemCount()
{
    // Implement the logic to query the total number of items in the database
    // Example: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dev.bobine"
}
```

Comment: sorry for the monstrous delay, but your solution works, thanks a lot!